# javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.server.db.test.ServletExample

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I just started learning Hibernate and Servlets.
I have a form (name, email), I fill that fields and the request goes to the server.
Then I fetch the data from server and print them.
This WORKS CORRECTLY!

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("userName");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();

    response.getWriter().println("<html>");
    response.getWriter().println("<head>");
    response.getWriter().println("<title>This is a response</title>");
    response.getWriter().println("<head>");
    response.getWriter().println("<body>");

    response.getWriter().println("<br>Your name is: " + name);
    response.getWriter().println("<br>Your email is: " + email);
    response.getWriter().println("<br>Your IP address is: " + ip);

    response.getWriter().println("</body>");
    response.getWriter().println("</html>");

}
```

Also I have a DB (db and .xml files are properly configured, ping is succesful, mapping is written) and Hibernate code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Data data = new Data();
    data.setUserName(name);
    data.setUserEmail(email);
    session.save(data);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Also I have a Data class:

```
@Entity
public class Data {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int Id;
    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;

//getteres, setters...
}
```

But if I put this code into the Servlet, I get an HTTP error 500. The error message as I can determine it is this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.server.db.test.ServletExample org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11P‌​rotocol.java:602) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How can I put my info from the server to the database?

my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Example02</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ServletExample</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.server.db.test.ServletExample</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

hibernate cfg file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">***</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

         <mapping class="org.server.db.test.Data" />
         <mapping class="org.server.db.test.ServletExample" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Take a look on the exception: it definitely presents either in log file on standard error of your server. The exception will probably tell you a tip. If you cannot understand it put it here and we will try.

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.server.db.test.ServletExample
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
......

Comment: are there no inner exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.server.db.test.ServletExample

To the point, under the covers of the server, the following construct has failed with an exception:

```
ServletExample servletExample = new ServletExample();
```

The exact cause is mentioned further down in the stacktrace. It's the bottommost one. Read the server log to find it. This problem has at least *nothing* to do with "Saving data from UI to the database".